# gulp-uglify не минифицирует es6. Нужен аналог или совет как включить поддержку es6

Tags: gulp

Всем доброго времени суток. Да, gulp-uglify не минифицирует es6.
Использую es6. Банальные `let`, `const`, `()=>{}` ничего сверх, а при минификации получаю:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проверил опытным путем, проблема именно в es6, если переписываю код по старым стандартам, все работает.

Как исправить данную проблему с помощью старого доброго gulp-uglify? Ведь наверняка как-то можно.
Ну а если совсем нельзя, буду признателен за совет другого сборщика на gulp

```js
var gulp           = require('gulp'),
    uglify         = require('gulp-uglify'),
```

```js
gulp.task('build', function() {

    var buildJs = gulp.src([
        'app/js/scripts.min.js',
    ])
        // .pipe(uglify())// когда раскомментирую, перестанет работать
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));

});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44958216/how-to-minify-es6-functions-with-gulp-uglify

Comment: Спасибо! Это то, что нужно!

Comment: Сделайте это ответом, не хочет отмечать, что дубликат, т.к. не на русском. Отмечу как правильный

Comment: Ну, делать ответом уже, я вижу, неактуально, вы и сами ответили. :) И это хорошо, потому что делать из комментария-ссылки более-менее нормальный ответ мне было бы очень лениво. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По мне лучше использовать [uglify-es](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-es) он в отличие от `babel` не переводит код в старый формат, для `gulp` есть [gulp-uglify-es](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglify-es)

Пример из документации

```
let gulp = require("gulp");
let rename = require("gulp-rename");
let uglify = require('gulp-uglify-es').default;

gulp.task("uglify", function () {
    return gulp.src("lib/bundle.js")
        .pipe(rename("bundle.min.js"))
        .pipe(uglify(/* options */))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("lib/"));
});
```

Comment: Согласен с Вами! Спасибо за дельный совет!

Answer (score 1):

Так же возможно собрать весь проект в один файл, прогнав через babel, и уже его минифицировать.

Comment: Извините, не могли бы вы поподробнее показать - как?

Answer (score 0):

Не могу отметить дубликатом, т.к. дубликатом является только русскоязычный вопрос.
Решение данной проблемы [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44958216/how-to-minify-es6-functions-with-gulp-uglify), мне подсказали, спасибо большое.

Чтобы `gulp-uglify` работал с `es6` надо установить `gulp-babel`. [Документация](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-babel)

```
npm install --save-dev gulp-babel babel-core babel-preset-env
```

Подключаю

```
var gulp           = require('gulp'),
    babel          = require('gulp-babel'),
    uglify         = require('gulp-uglify');
```

`task` сборки проекта

```
gulp.task('build', function() {

    //.. другие подзадачи

    var buildJs = gulp.src([
        'app/js/scripts.min.js',
    ])
        .pipe(babel({
            presets: ['env']
        }))
        .pipe(uglify()) // Теперь это работает
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));

});
```