# gulp watch вылетает с Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch

Во всех проектах один и тот же `gulpfile.js` живёт без изменений уже почти год, всё работало прекрасно и буквально вчера таск `gulp watch` начал вылетать со странной ошибкой:

```
Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end
at writeAfterEnd (_stream_writable.js:248:12)
at ObjectTransform.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:296:5)
at Transform.ondata (_stream_readable.js:693:20)
at Transform.emit (events.js:198:13)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
at Transform.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
at Transform.push (_stream_transform.js:151:32)
at Transform.afterTransform (_stream_transform.js:92:10)
at Transform.transform [as _transform] (/home/front/Projects/project/node_modules/gulp-eslint/index.js:82:3)
Emitted 'error' event at:
at DestroyableTransform.onerror (/home/front/Projects/project/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:640:52)
at DestroyableTransform.emit (events.js:198:13)
at DestroyableTransform._transform (/home/front/Projects/project/node_modules/gulp-babel/index.js:54:9)
at DestroyableTransform.Transform._read (/home/front/Projects/project/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:184:10)
at DestroyableTransform.Transform._write (/home/front/Projects/project/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:172:83)
at doWrite (/home/front/Projects/project/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:428:64)
at writeOrBuffer (/home/front/Projects/project/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:417:5)
at DestroyableTransform.Writable.write (/home/front/Projects/project/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:334:11)
at DestroyableTransform.ondata (/home/front/Projects/project/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:619:20)
at DestroyableTransform.emit (events.js:198:13)
```

Причём, вылетает не сразу: одно изменение в любом `.js`-файле сохраняет, а при втором вылетает с ошибкой. С `.css`-файлами такой проблемы нет - там, как и раньше, сохраняется любое количество изменений.

**Пробовала:**

- апгрейдить и даунгрейдить `npm`: **не помогло**, ошибка всё та же
- использовать `gulp-watch` вместо `gulp.watch`: **не удалось**, ошибка исчезла, но изменения в файле не отслеживались вообще
- апгрейдить `gulp` 3.9.1 => 4.0.0: **не удалось**, `error: pathspec '4.0' did not match any file(s) known to git` - видимо, эту версию сейчас оттуда не достать
- гуглить ошибку: **не помогло**, т.к. большинство ответов связано с серверами на `Node.js` и кодом для них (которого в моём проекте нет). Гугление ошибки в связке с `gulp`, `eslint`, `browsersync` тоже не дало особых результатов.
- закомментировать в `gulpfile.js` строку с таской для `eslint` (в ошибке есть путь до него): **не помогло**, путь сменяется на модуль из следующей строки - `babel`

**gulpfile.js**:

```
'use strict';

const gulp = require('gulp');

// utilities
const runSequence = require('run-sequence');
const del = require('del');
const cache = require('gulp-cache');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

// sourcemaps
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

// javascript
const uglify = require("gulp-uglify-es").default();
const babel = require('gulp-babel');
const eslint = require('gulp-eslint');
const concat = require('gulp-concat');

// css
const postcss = require('gulp-postcss');
const csso = require('gulp-csso');

// images
const imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
const svgo = require('gulp-svgo');

const src_dir = 'src/**';
const css_src = `src/blocks/**/*.css`;
const js_src = `src/blocks/**/*.js`;
const dest_dir = 'dist';
const dest_dir_css = `${dest_dir}/css`
const dest_dir_js = `${dest_dir}/js`

const postcssPlugins = [
    require('postcss-import'),
    require('precss'),
    require('postcss-short'),
    require('postcss-use'),
    require('postcss-utilities'),
    require('autoprefixer'),
    require('cssnext'),
    require('postcss-normalize')({ forceImport: true }),
    require("postcss-reporter")({ clearReportedMessages: true }),
];

const htmlminConfig = {
    collapseWhitespace: true,
    removeComments: true
};

var count = require('gulp-count');

gulp.task('js', () => {
  return gulp.src(js_src)
        .pipe(count('## js-files selected'))
        .pipe( concat ('bundle.js') )
        .pipe( sourcemaps.init() )
        .pipe( babel() )
        .pipe( eslint() )
        .pipe( uglify )
        .pipe( sourcemaps.write('.') )
        .pipe( gulp.dest(dest_dir_js) )
});

gulp.task('css', () =>
    gulp.src(css_src)
        .pipe( sourcemaps.init() )
        .pipe( postcss(postcssPlugins) )
        .pipe( sourcemaps.write('.') )
        .pipe( concat ('bundle.css') )
        .pipe( gulp.dest(dest_dir_css) )
        .pipe( browserSync.reload({ stream: true }))
);

gulp.task('browserSync', () =>
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: './'
        },
    })
);

gulp.task('images', () =>
    gulp.src('src/images/**/*.+(png|jpg|gif|svg)')
        //.pipe( cache( imagemin() ) )
        .pipe( svgo() )
        .pipe( gulp.dest('dist/images') )
);

gulp.task('watch', ['browserSync'], () => {
    gulp.watch(css_src, ['css']);
    gulp.watch(js_src, ['js']);
    gulp.watch(dest_dir_js, browserSync.reload);
});

gulp.task('clean', () => del([dest_dir]) );
gulp.task('default', ['clean'], () => runSequence('css', 'js', 'images') );
```

**Структура проекта:**

```
dist
|__css
|  |__bundle.css
|
|__images  
|
|__js
   |__bundle.js
   |__bundle.js.map

src
|__blocks
|  |__block1
|  |  |__block1.css
|  |  |__block1.js
|  |  
|  |__block2 
|  |  |__ ...
|  |
|  |__ ...
|
|__images
|
|__fonts
```

Может быть, вы уже сталкивались с подобной проблемой или видели решение - поделитесь, пожалуйста, буду безумно благодарна! Собирать всё заново после каждой ошибки - грустно :с

Comment: Может быть проблема из-за gulp.watch(dest_dir_js, browserSync.reload);, попробуйте удалить его и добавить в конец js таски .pipe( browserSync.reload({ stream: true }))

Comment: @DmitryDavydov, не помогло - всё так же при первом изменении работает, при втором вылетает с той же ошибкой

Comment: Попробуйте вырезать по очереди все плагины, иногда бывает что какой-нибудь старой версии или просто конфликтует, вплоть до

```
gulp.task('js', () => {
  return gulp.src(js_src)
        .pipe( gulp.dest(dest_dir_js) )
});

gulp.task('watch'], () => {
    gulp.watch(js_src, ['js']);
});
```

Comment: @DmitryDavydov, таким образом удалось установить, что проблема с `gulp-uglify` - если его `.pipe` закомментировать, то всё продолжает работать. Но в чём причина пока не могу понять.
Спасибо за идею :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас используется gulp-uglify-es, и судя по этому https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/784678/343238 ответу его можно заменить на обычный gulp-uglify - т.к. вы уже прогнали файлы через babel.

А вторая штука, которая скорее всего и причина изначальной ошибки - у вас в конфиге вызов uglify идёт так

```
const uglify = require("gulp-uglify-es").default();
...
    .pipe( uglify )
```

Но в документации иной вариант

```
let uglify = require('gulp-uglify-es').default;
...
    .pipe(uglify())
```

И скорее всего ошибка в том, что default() возвращает поток, который в вашем случае используется один раз, а на второй раз уже закрыт, в то время с вариантом как в документации uglify() возвращает новый поток на каждый запуск таски

Comment: Вы правы, дело было в моей невнимательности - убирала и добавляла скобки после uglify в `.pipe(uglify())`, но совершенно не замечала их отсутствие после default. 

Спасибо огромное!



P.S.: по поводу использования `gulp-uglify-es` вместо просто `gulp-uglify`+`babel` - это тоже было единственным решением, которое я смогла найти, когда у меня в очередной раз сломалась сборка¯ \ _ (ツ) _ / ¯  Надеюсь, что в ходе ближайших экспериментов разберусь и с этой ошибкой.

Answer (score 2):

Как оказалось, проблему вызывал `gulp-uglify` - если его `.pipe` был закомментирован, всё работало нормально. В причине этой ошибки я пока разобраться не смогла, поэтому заменила его на `gulp-js-minify` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-js-minify).

P.S.: если вы знаете, в чём может быть ошибка и как разобраться с `gulp-uglify` - напишите, пожалуйста, буду благодарна за помощь.